# python urllib HTTP Error on website that doesn't require authentication

Tags: python, urllib

1. I am try to read this website via Python: https://misc.interactivebrokers.com/cstools/contract_info/v3.9/index.php?action=Futures%20Search&entityId=a19207303&lang=en&wlId=GEN&showEntities=Y

I can open this link on any browser. No authentication is required. But I am not able to read it in Python. Here's my code

```
import urllib.request as web

ibweb = 'https://misc.interactivebrokers.com/cstools/contract_info/v3.9/index.php?' + \
        'action=Futures%20Search&entityId=a19207303&lang=en&wlId=GEN&showEntities=Y'

scode = web.urlopen(ibweb).read()
```

The error I get is `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request`. Here is the full set of tracebook for the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\PF\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.3\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3035, in run_code
exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  File "<ipython-input-96-ce48d11587fe>", line 1, in <module>
web.urlopen(ibweb)

  File "C:\PF\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.3\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\urllib\request.py", line 161, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)

  File "C:\PF\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.3\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\urllib\request.py", line 469, in open
response = meth(req, response)

  File "C:\PF\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.3\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\urllib\request.py", line 579, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)

  File "C:\PF\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.3\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\urllib\request.py", line 507, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)

  File "C:\PF\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.3\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\urllib\request.py", line 441, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)

  File "C:\PF\WinPython-64bit-3.4.3.3\python-3.4.3.amd64\lib\urllib\request.py", line 587, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)

urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Why am I getting this error, when I can open this link on any browser?

2. I get a similar error when I try to read this link: http://www.cboe.com/delayedquote/ssfquote.aspx, although not sure if it is for the same reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, why don't use [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) instead of `urllib`?

```
>>> ibweb = 'https://misc.interactivebrokers.com/cstools/contract_info/v3.9/index.php?' + \
            'action=Futures%20Search&entityId=a19207303&lang=en&wlId=GEN&showEntities=Y'

>>> import requests
>>> requests.get(ibweb)
<Response [200]>
>>>
```

Comment: can you tell me how to process the requests further, i.e. display the contents? I too get this `<Response [200]>`, but what do I do to see the contents of the Response?

Comment: `response = requests.get(ibweb)`   and     `content = response.content`

Comment: Here is a link to documentation: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/

Comment: @GabrielIlharco: Yeah, but I'd recommend use `response.text`. Because as the document said: [*You can also access the response body as bytes, for non-text requests*](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content)  <-- use `response.content` in this case.  So if you're trying to get an image, or audio file, use `response.content`, otherwise, use `response.text`.